# How to remove a pattern that may or may not exist at the end using regex

Tags: c#, regex

I want to capture without including a certain pattern (anything in parenthesis) that may or may not exist at the end of the string. I want to capture everything but the string "(exclude)" in the following 3 examples:

```
**aaaaaa**

**bbbbbb** (exclude)

**cccccc**
```

I tried the following regex:

```
(.+)(?:\(.+\)){0,1}
```

Comment: Please specify language/technology you're using in tags

Comment: Try [`^(.+?)(?:\(.*\))?$`](https://regex101.com/r/eXmCcu/1)

Comment: BTW, you may just remove a substring in parentheses at the end of the string: `var res = Regex.Replace(s, @"\s*\([^()]*\)'\s*$", "");` (that is, if you do not have any parentheses inside the `(...)` substring.

Comment: Thanks Wiktor, that worked great!

Comment: Wiktor, thanks for the replace suggestion. Unfortunately, the regex needs to be defined declaratively in a file outside the program.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use your matching approach with

```
^(.+?)(?:\(.*\))?$
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/eXmCcu/1). Basically, you need to add anchors to your pattern and use a lazy quantifier with the first dot matching pattern.

**Details**

- `^` - start of the string
- `(.+?)` - Group 1: one or more chars other than newline as *few* as possible (`*?` allows the regex engine to test the next optional subpattern first, and only expand this one upon no match)
- `(?:\(.*\))?` - an optional sequence of

  - `\(` - a `(` char
  - `.*` - any 0+ chars other than newline as many as possible
  - `\)` - a `)` char
- `$` - end of string.

In C#:

```
var m = Regex.Match(s, @"^(.+?)(?:\(.*\))?$");
var result = string.Empty;
if (m.Success) {
    result = m.Groups[1].Value;
}
```

You may also remove a substring in parentheses at the end of the string if it has no other parentheses inside using

```
var res = Regex.Replace(s, @"\s*\([^()]*\)\s*$", "");
```

See [another demo](https://regex101.com/r/EeseQd/1). Here, `\s*\([^()]*\)\s*$` matches 0+ whitespaces, `(`, any 0+ chars other than `(` and `)` (`[^()]*`) and then 0+ whitespaces at the end of the string.