# How to define optional suffix in regex?

Tags: regex

I have a string as an input which may or may not end with some suffix. Let it be suffix "xyz". I want to capture everything that is before this suffix. For example:

if input is: "abc xyz", then "abc " should be captured (without suffix)

if input is just: "abc" then "abc" should be captured

My thought was that simple regex like:

```
(.*)(xyz)?
```

will work, meaning any data following by optional xyz suffix. But in case of input: "abc xyz" the captured group is the whole input instead of "abc "

Comment: It's easier to take the whole string, then chop off any suffix: `s/xyz$//`. What language/tool/library are you using?

Comment: Just make your capturing non-greedy: `(.*?)(xyz)?`

Comment: In fact, it should be `^(.*?)(xyz)?$`

Comment: Thank you, Wiktor, I modified your solution a bit ending up with: `^(.*?)(?:xyz)?$` in order not to capture suffix itself into a second group

Comment: It is next to identical to [my previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48805244/3832970), so, decided to close.

Comment: @RhinoLarva It does using `javascript` as the engine. I just checked both. You may be confusing the `Full match` which `Group 1` or `Group 2`.